# nginx doesn't stream file through thin runned rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, streaming, thin, sendfile

Ive a rails 4 app running which is used for file exchange. Its basicly running very well but when I try to download a file that is bigger then some hundred mb its getting slow. I think this is because nginx doenst stream the file it's first loading the file to the ram and then sends it.

I have `sendfile on;` in my nginx config and `config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header` set to true in my `config/environments/production.conf`. Im using thin as a webserver.

Does anyone have an idea about what Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think [thin](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/) supports Rails implementation of streaming [out of the box](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/thin-ruby/8iZGaoFDIA0/9Ephezg-qyYJ).

There was [some work](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/commit/06cdd8777d5a5dc46adf9a31f8152effea50be78) done on that front, but afaik it was never merged to master branch.

Instead of `thin`, our team switched to using [puma](http://puma.io) on our local machines, and we're using `passenger` on our production server (although in the light of recent [article](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/ruby-app-server-arena-pt1) from Engine Yard, we're considering switching our production app server to either `unicorn` on `puma`).